# how to add vitamio dependecny on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, vitamio

I can stream video url using vitamio in eclipse, but recently I have switched to android studio and I want to add vitamio library as a dependency in the gradle file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

add

```
dependencies {
compile 'me.neavo:vitamio:4.2.2'
}
```

in build.gradle of module

Comment: It says:
Error:Failed to find: me.neavo:vitamio:4.2.2

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/me.neavo/vitamio/4.2.2 please see here. if there is any problem you can report also

Comment: @SuhailMehta yes me too get It says: Error:Failed to find: me.neavo:vitamio:4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

First, add gradle dependency and repository to the build.gradle

```
repositories { maven { url
'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/me.neavo/vitamio' } }
```

Under the repository add dependency as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'me.neavo', name: 'vitamio', version: '4.2.2'
}
```

Then sync the Project